# JDBC Slow Query Report is reporting queries with incorrect run time

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I added the SlowQueryReport JDBC interceptor to my application and it has been logging query failures for every single query made. The queries are executing like normal and returning with data nearly instantly (definitely < 100 ms), and yet every query is being logged with a message that looks like:

```
Failed Query Report SQL=select status from user where user_.id=?; time=1456183877324 ms;
```

I would suspect that the reason the SlowQueryReport is marking the query as a failure is because it somehow is logging the query as taking 1456183877324 ms... 46.175287840055816 years, which takes us to 1970 the starting Unix time.

Anyone know what's going on?

The Slow Query Report threshhold has been set to 100ms.

System:

- Application is on AWS EC2 using Amazon Linux.
- Application is running on Tomcat 7.
- Database is PostgreSQL 9.3.10 running on AWS RDS.
- The date on the EC2 instance is: "Tue Feb 23 00:16:09 UTC 2016" via "date".
- The date on the DB is "2016-02-23 00:16:06.321741+00" via "SELECT NOW();"
- The JDBC version is tomcat-jdbc, version 7.0.50.